# Why is my regex not replacing my string in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

I'm trying to get rid of the protocol and domain from a URL in jQuery with `.replace()` and regex, but it leaves the string exactly the same no matter what.

```
var selectedDocumentUrl = "http://mysite.test.com/files/somefile.pdf";
var assetUrl = selectedDocumentUrl.replace('/http://[^\/]+/g', '');
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MN7xH/2/) of the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass a regular expression to replace() not a string literal

```
var assetUrl = selectedDocumentUrl.replace(/http:\/\/[^\/]+/g, '');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fAWVr/)

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  Thank you for also pointing out in the code that I had to escape the slashes in the protocol.